# How can I set multiple middlewere in Controller's constructor in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

`Kernel.php`

```php
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
'super_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdmin::class,
'seller' => \App\Http\Middleware\Seller::class,
```

> I have created three different `middlewere`. Here are those in `kernel.php`

For Example I want to give the dashboard access to all these three users. `admin`, `super_admin` and `seller`.

`DashboardController.php`

```php
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['super_admin', 'admin', 'seller']);
}
```

**But this multiple middlewere didn't work**

**No error, But I can't access admin route**

**Single middlewere works perfectly**

**References**

`web.php`

```php
Route::get('admin', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
Route::get('admin/shops', 'DashboardController@shops')->name('dashboard.shops');
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What does _"But this multiple middleware didn't work"_ mean? What error are you getting? you definitely can pass multiple middlewares as an array to `$this->middleware()`.

Comment: No error... But I can't access the admin route...

Comment: The problem is probably that you have three different middlewares for different roles, you should have one middleware, that you can pass all roles that should have access, otherwise a `super_admin` has access, but because he is not an `admin` or `seller`, he does not have access. In order to access the route the request has to pass through all middlewares.

Comment: yes. I have three different middlewere for three roles.

Comment: How to do that? Please

Comment: @ImrulHasan Have a look at [middleware parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#middleware-parameters), that way you can pass multiple roles that should have access to the middleware and then you can check if the authenticated user has any of them.

Comment: Thanks bro.... for reference... ❤

Comment: You may want to have a look at [route-filters](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) in case you are trying to protect specific routes. You can [group](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups) them aswell :)

Comment: thanks bro.. for your suggestion.... @Pilan

Comment: Bro. It works fine.... ❤

Comment: Bro.... I have posted the solution after reading those references. Please have a look. If it was right way.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I have fixed those problems**

#### Special thanks to **Remul** and **Pilan** bro for their valuable references.

### Step 1

`Middlewere/AdminPanel.php`

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $super_adminRole, $adminRole,  $sellerRole)
{
    $roles = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->role->pluck('name')->toArray() : [];

    if (in_array($super_adminRole, $roles)) {
        return $next($request);
    } else if (in_array($adminRole, $roles)) {
        return $next($request);
    } else if (in_array($sellerRole, $roles)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return Redirect::route('home');
}
```

> In the `roles` table there are 3 roles. `super_admin`, `admin` and `seller`.

> In the array `$roles` contain those roles.

So in the `if` condition null comparing with `null` gives `false` hence the condition will not satisfied.

### Step 2

`Kernel.php`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'adminPanel' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminPanel::class,
];
```

### Step 3

`DashboardController.php`

### **4 Variations**

```php
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['adminPanel:super_admin,admin,seller']);
}
```

> Here `super_admin`, `admin` and `seller` can access

```php
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['adminPanel:super_admin,null,null']);
}
```

> Here `super_admin` can access

```php
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['adminPanel:null,admin,null']);
}
```

> Here `admin` can access

```php
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['adminPanel:null,null,seller']);
}
```

> Here `seller` can access

---